# Addressing Sir or Ma'am to Transgender or Androgynous looking individuals

Tags: professionalism, gender, lgbtq

I am manning the front desk at a tech conference and I ran into a situation where I did not know if I should address an individual with Sir or Ma'am. My salutation is "Hello Sir/Ma'am Welcome to Tech Camp! How may I help you?"

But given the sensitive topic, I am at a loss as to what to say.

I've reached out to the conference's organizers, but my immediate supervisor cannot be reached (phone, slack, text) or found.

Comment: Whenever you are the front face on any event, drop the gender in your greeting. Regardless of who you talk to.  "Hello. Welcome to Tech Camp. I will be happy to assist you today"

Comment: Why would you feel the need to ever say hello sir or hello ma'am?

Comment: @HLGEM indoctrination from educational and cultural development addressed towards unknown individuals.

Comment: @sumelic received no specific training or procedure as a volunteer. Absent of an established SOP, default behavior is to rack up the formality.

Comment: I have never heard of a man not liking to be called sir, but I have hardly ever met a woman who like to be referred to as ma'am (which indicates advanced age to most women). It really is an outdated term that needs to go away.

Comment: @HLGEM hi, I'm a man who doesn't like being called "sir". (Although I generally don't care enough to actually complain about it)

Comment: What you should say is going to vary greatly by company and location.

Comment: @HLGEM - Former Military NCO's often have an aversion to being called sir.    Also it is quite common for members of the LGBT community to dislike the superlative quality of the term.

Comment: I found this suggestion to use 'Mx.' but I don't think it's caught on yet. Plus I'm not sure how to pronounce it. "Mix"? http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3066043/A-new-title-transgender-people-join-Mr-Mrs-Miss-used-driving-licences-bank-details-government-departments.html

Comment: I don't think you can assume someone is transgender just because of their appearance.  If you really can't tell which they are, probably better to leave out the pronoun.

Comment: @HLGEM I don't like being sir-ed.  Makes me feel old.  I also highly dislike all styles of formality.  I won't say anything about it (because really, that would be odd) but I prefer not to get it.  I also don't like to be called Mr. Sechan.  Call me by my name.  Mr Sechan was my father the teacher.

Comment: Just for the basic fact of it, "Sir" can be used adressing both genders - which leads me to have the opinion it should be used to the "expanded list" of genders - no offense meant but I don't know how many there are and I generally don't care (people are people). If you are adressing royals, you cannot use Sir to a Queen, it should be Mam (like "ham") - but then the title gives it away. A Queen shall per definition be adressed "Mam". Any other official can be adressed with "Sir" unless the title is clearly gendered, then it is "Madam" (or "Ms" at your peril) btw: English speaking countries

Comment: @StianYttervik in the Uk its Your Majesty on the first occasion  then ma'am there after - my first company had a royal visit so there was a briefing document

Comment: In some communities it's becoming common to put preferred pronouns in name badges even when preference is to use the ones matching appearance. That may be enough to guess honorific, though if the preference is a non-traditional one there may not _be_ an established honorific. In which case you dodge, apologies and ask their preference, or guess and apologies profusely if wrong, explaining that you're still learning the new conventions. Or substitute something like "Honorable" (or, at a programming camp, 'Hacker") which is equally silly for everyone...

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Just drop "Sir/Ma'am" entirely and say:

*"Hello and welcome to tech camp! How may I help you?"*

It doesn't seem like such a formal environment that omitting that would be too casual.

You could also consider addressing everyone that way, not just transgender or androgynous individuals. That would sidestep the issue entirely and give you one less thing you have to think about when you're welcoming them or helping them out.

Comment: "Hello and welcome ..." sounds a bit less like something's missing IMO.

Comment: I say sir/ma’am to everyone if I do not know them personally. I rack up the formal addressing by default. The mental error code was raised when meeting the aforementioned individuals. But your answer is noted and being applied.

Comment: @FrankFYC I totally understand. I also default to being highly formal in such situations. I'm glad I could help, though.

Comment: The OP seems to be using sir/madam as a way to insert formality into the statement. In such a situation, something along the lines of "Good morning/afternoon/evening, welcome to tech camp. How may I be of service?" may be closer to the desired degree of formality.

Comment: @Cronax the require level of formality varies by country  in the UK the only person I would call "ma'am" would be the Queen - but I agree with dropping the sir / ma'am

Comment: @BernhardBarker Perhaps in the stiff etiquette of the 20th century it would have sounded like something is missing, but not in the 21st.

Answer (score 15):

> I am manning the front desk at a tech conference and I ran into a
>   situation where I did not know if I should address an individual with
>   Sir or Ma'am. My salutation is "Hello Sir/Ma'am Welcome to Tech Camp!
>   How may I help you?"

There is *never* a need to mention gender when greeting someone *in person*.

"Hello! Welcome to Tech Camp! How may I help you?" is completely appropriate.

Comment: Some cultures require honorifics, and those honorifics are often gendered. It seems quite clear that the OP is in and/or from such a culture. I don't see what being in person has to do with it.

Comment: The fact that the OP is asking this question is extremely strong evidence that they are in/from such a culture. Your mention of them being in the US is a non sequitur. You seem to be relying on the premise that such culture does not exist in the US, which is both absurd and disrespectful, and a premise that you didn't have the decency to explicitly assert.

Answer (score 9):

I have organized a number of conferences in the American South, where simply forgoing salutations is socially uncouth.

In your case it’s too late to really do anything about it, but this is the reason at registration people are given options to submit their pronouns nowadays.  But what use are pronouns really in a conference setting? Pronouns are for talking **about** someone, not **to** someone. Honorifics and salutations are for talking **to** them.  The organizers should either ask for salutation at registration and print it on the badge, or have stickers people can choose from. (Sir, Ma’am, Mx, none, and so on).

For example, from a real event in Texas:

[image]

Without that, just do your best, accept correction quickly and graciously, and consider substituting something more neutral like “friend” when really puzzled.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm ... there are intergenerational and inter-subcultural (word?) considerations here.

Specifically, many people (myself included!) were raised with the notion that omitting the honorific in a formal situation is staggeringly rude.  For this and for practical reasons -- I doubt that there's enough cultural impetus to discard honorifics entirely, for the benefit of the small amount of people who are in honorific-ambiguous territory -- I'd suggest the following:

*Take your best shot on honorific.*  The vast majority of people, it's pretty clear which one to use.  If you get it wrong, person will tell you what he or she wants.

I've been asked by someone to use 'zir' before.  I gamely promised that I'd try.

Comment: You're wrong about there not being a cultural impetus to getting rid of honorifics.  I haven't been called sir in months.  In the US, sir is only really a common thing in the south.  Almost nobody will care that you leave out an honorific, but many will be HIGHLY offended if called the wrong one.

Comment: @GabeSechan I'll say that there doesn't seem to be a "cultural consensus" any more on a lot of topics, this being one.  Am very interested to see how it plays out.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere hence the "try".  I clearly didn't quite get it...

Answer (score -3):

There’s no guarantee that you get it right for everyone. And you can’t even ask because some people will find it rude to be asked.

The safest is to avoid calling anyone “sir” or “madam”. And I don’t know about “madam”, but many men don’t like being called “sir”.

Comment: Today on "things that never happened"...

Answer (score -4):

A friend pointed me to the essay at https://www.them.us/story/gender-neutral-pronouns-101-they-them-xe-xem

I can't vouch for that essay's correctness, but it seems plausible, and suggests a solution:

Traditionally, proper manners is always to introduce yourself first and then invite the other person to do likewise. This can be extended to stating your own preferred pronouns (even if they are the older ones) as an implied invitation for the other party to inform you of theirs.

Perhaps:

"Welcome! I am Doctor Archibald Farnsworth, but most folks call me Arch. My pronouns are ze and zim. Whom do I have the pleasure of meeting, and how would you like to be addressed?"

If your going to insist upon formality, do it right.

Comment: This type of behaviour is completely out of place IMHO

Comment: This type of behavior used to be common (well, minus the pronouns) and is becoming common again as people who care about the issue make an effort to normalize the use of nontraditional pronouns. The simplest alternative -- as others have said -- is to avoid the gendered formalism in the first place, but it sounded as if the querant's culture made that an unacceptable choice. The more complicated alternative, if the culture really does require them, would be to develop non-gendered formalisms -- but that has to be done by folks in that culture and in those communities, not by us.

Comment: I was referencing the pronouns. Can't envision a place where speaking that way would be acceptable, except in a very democratically liberal-progressive USA subculture.

Comment: As I say, the pronouns are becoming more common, for exactly the reasons this question is based on. Get used to folks stating their preference, and get used to being implicitly invited to state yours. It may not have hit your part of the world yet, but unless we establish a non-gendered form first it's going to. There's a lot we can't envision if we haven't seen it happening.

Comment: The implication behind asking for pronouns is that there is more than one gender, and half the population likely is not amenable to having this forced down their throats. Asking this type of question would therefore trigger other tensions. If a person's appearance is sufficiently androgynous to warrant asking about their gender, fine; but if they are sporting a full beard and collared shirt... asking for their pronouns may be perceived as a borderline insult to their appearance.

Comment: @DenisG.Labrecque Not in my experience. I have friends who are cis straight but use alternative pronouns for various reasons ranging from support of friends who aren't to disliking gendered language to simple preference. And stating your own, while not asking the other person's, does not ply anything about them. They are welcome to think I'm an idiot; I'd rather be thought one than be one. Again, the better answer is to drop the formality entirely. "Real writers rewrite to avoid the problem."